# Redirect to a subdirectory frontpage using without using a WP plugin- what files to edit, and how?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, template-redirect

### My situation

I have a multisite setup, where I use subdirectories for different languages. I use the main homepage for English and subdirectories for other languages, as follows:

mywesbite.com : English language frontpage

mywebsite.com/jp/ : Japanese language frontpage

### What I want to do

I would like to redirect people who live in Japan to the Japanese language ffrontpage ***without using a WordPress plugin***.

### What I have tried

Using the [geoplugin.com](https://www.geoplugin.com/) , as inspired by the [3rd answer of this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address) I edited the theme `header.php`  file by adding the following at the very beginning

```
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
if ($countrycode=='JP'){
        header( 'Location: https://mywebsite.com/jp/' );
        exit;
    }
```

### The problem

However, I get the following error

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> An error occurred during a connection to mywebsite.com.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

**Note**: the redirecting works fine with an external website, for example

```
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
if ($countrycode=='JP'){
        header( 'Location: https://anotherwebsite.com' );
        exit;
    }
```

Is there a way to fix this error?

I am also open to other solutions not using a WP plugin.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Perhaps your host doesn't allow 'file_get_contents'. Test the value of $countrycode to see what is being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like every time any page is loaded, if it meets the condition, it will try to redirect. So, if you're viewing from Japan, and you hit the top-level site, you'll be redirected. But then when you are redirected, the `header.php` code once again will see that you're viewing from Japan, and try to redirect. And so on, and so forth.

So a solution to the immediate problem would be to add a condition. Only try to redirect if the visitor is currently viewing the top-level site.

```
<?php
// Only if this is the top-level site
if(get_current_blog_id() == 1) {
    $a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    $countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
    if ($countrycode=='JP'){
        header( 'Location: https://mywebsite.com/jp/' );
    exit;
    }
}
?>
```

However, this may not be ideal. If you have content that other visitors will be viewing on the top-level site, every time they load a page, this check is going to run and slow things down. So, it would be much better to find a way to cookie visitors and not be running server-side logic every time a page is loaded.

Also, if you've added this code to an existing theme's `header.php` file, it's going to be overwritten every time you update the theme. So you'll want to create a child theme if this is still the approach you want to take.